# How to install Remmina RDP Plugin?

Tags: software-installation

I changed my os from Ubuntu 16.10 to elementary OS and it's good but I have problems to use remmina on elementary. I try to connect to other servers using RDP but in the scrren appear the message that "Protocol Plugin RDP isn't installed".

Answer (score 2):

for me

```
sudo apt install remmina-plugin-rdp
```

worked fine!